# Переключение данных в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите скрипт для замены данных в таблице
т.е. хочется сделать чтобы по нажатию российский рубль или другая иная валюта менялась цена в таблице с прайсом:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Тип программы</span></th>
<th><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>с 01.04 по 31.05.2016
</strong></span></th>
<th><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>с 01.06 по 30.09.2016
</strong></span></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">Программа 1</a></td>
<td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">2350 RUB  за день</span></td>
<td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">2540 RUB  за день</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><a href="#">Программа 2</a></td>
<td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">2150 RUB  за день</span></td>
<td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">2350 RUB  за день</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь я правильно понял вопрос.
Курс валюты ну незнаю, но его надо откуда то брать или фиксировать...
Удачи.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

var courseUSD = 65; //текущий курс RUB к USD (просто цифра понравилась)  

  $('button[name="changeprice"]').on({
    'click': function changePrice(e) {
      $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('USD');
      $('.price').each(function(i, item) {
        $(item).text($(e.currentTarget)
          .hasClass('USD') ?
          ($(item).data().priceRub / courseUSD).toFixed(2) + ' USD' :
          $(item).data().priceRub + ' RUB');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Тип программы</span>
      </th>
      <th><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>с 01.04 по 31.05.2016
</strong></span>
      </th>
      <th><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>с 01.06 по 30.09.2016
</strong></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Программа 1</a>
      </td>
      <td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span class="price" data-price-rub="2350">2350 RUB</span> за день</span>
      </td>
      <td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span class="price" data-price-rub="2540">2540 RUB</span> за день</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">Программа 2</a>
      </td>
      <td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span class="price" data-price-rub="2150">2150 RUB</span> за день</span>
      </td>
      <td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span class="price" data-price-rub="2350">2350 RUB</span> за день</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button name="changeprice">Change Price USD/RUB</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я понял как корректно сформулировать вопрос. Я Чутка не правильно это сделал. Хочется цифры на которые подключать задавать самому.

Comment: Ну в вопросе не было такой постановки задачи, поэтому я и задал курс и перерасчет повесил в функции. Но если можно указывать фиксом в данных какие цифры нужно подставлять то это упращает.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил сюда

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $('button[name="changeprice"]').on({
    'click': function changePrice(e) {
      $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('USD');
      $('.price').each(function(i, item) {
        $(item).text($(e.currentTarget)
          .hasClass('USD') ?
          $(item).data().priceUsd + ' USD' :
          $(item).data().priceRub + ' RUB');
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"><span class="price" data-price-rub="2350" data-price-usd="35">2350 RUB</span> за день</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button name="changeprice">Change Price USD/RUB</button>
```

Я правильно код отредактировал? Или его надо упростить?

Comment: Да такой вариант нормальный.